# The smallest value of $2x^2-2xy+5y^2-6y$

Tags: polynomials

> Find the smallest value of
>
> $$2x^2-2xy+5y^2-6y$$

What I tried:

I used differentiation to find the answer is $-2$, and I'm looking for another way to solve this question, which is factorization. If I could make that polynomial go into the form of $a(x-t)^2+b(y-v)^2 +c$ then the answer would be $c$. Can you please help me solve it by factorization?

Comment: you can not have all of $a,b,c,t,v$ are constant in the expression $a(x-t)^2+b(y-v)^2 +c$, since $2xy$ is there...

Comment: $$2 x^2-2 x y+5 y^2-6 y=2 \left(x-\frac{1}{3}\right)^2-2 \left(x-\frac{1}{3}\right) \left(y-\frac{2}{3}\right)+5 \left(y-\frac{2}{3}\right)^2-2$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$2x^2-2xy+5y^2-6y=\frac{1}{2}\left(2x-y\right)^2+\frac{1}{2}\left(3y-2\right)^2+\text{something}\,.$$

Comment: something = -2 ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

Let $2x^2-x(2y)+5y^2-6y-k=0$

As $x$ is real, the discriminant must be $\ge0$

i.e., $(2y)^2-4\cdot2(5y^2-6y-k)\ge0$

$\iff8k\le-36y^2+48y=16-(6y-4)^2\le16$

$\iff k\le?$

We can rearrange as a quadratic equation of $y$ as well & check for the discriminant:

$$5y^2-2y(x+3)+2x^2-k=0$$